# Passing POST RESTful message to WCF Proxy with WSO2 ESB

Tags: wcf, rest, wso2, wso2-esb

I am fairly new to WS02 ESB -- my company implemented it a few months ago.

Currently, I am attempting to put a REST layer over the top of a WCF service. The use case I am trying to implement is for a location api in which mobile apps (iphone, android) provide location data to the WCF service via RESTful xml.

My current data flow is structured like Mobile App -> REST API -> ESB Proxy -> WCF Service.

The xml provided to the REST endpoint in the payload is this:

```
<Location Partner='{API Parnert Name}' Code='{API Partner Code}' Password='{API Partner Password}' Generated='2013-04-16T16:30:15Z'>
  <Latitude>44.5881</Latitude>
  <Longitude>-89.581248</Longitude>
  <Accuracy>75.334</Accuracy>
  <MobileDeviceUID>A1000017B8B437</MobileDeviceUID>
</Location>
```

In order to route this xml through WSO2 ESB I have created an API and a Service Proxy. (Everything is running locally on my machine)

The API is configured like this:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="API_LOC" context="/WS1/Location">
   <resource methods="POST">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" category="DEBUG"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/WS1LocationProxy/AddLocation" format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
         <log level="full"/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

And my proxy is configured like this:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="WS1LocationProxy" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full" category="TRACE"/>
         <property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:54270/WS1LocationService.svc"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:54270/WS1LocationService.svc?wsdl"/>
   <parameter name="useOriginalwsdl">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="interface">WS1LocationService</parameter>
   <parameter name="serviceType">proxy</parameter>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

My main question is this: how can I transform the POST payload of the incoming REST request into the SOAP envelope needed for the WCF service in the proxy. I haven't been able to find good examples of such a process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to manually transform it..Incoming POST request will be converted to SOAP message for processing in ESB..
You can check that with a log mediator in your proxy..
In the insequence..just use a log mediator and see the output..

```
<log level="full" >
   <property name ="incoming message" value="*****"/>
</log>
```

Comment: thank you. that got me some insight into the data that was being passed through. From what I can tell I will need to transform some of the data. The incoming SOAP message into the REST api does not match the required SOAP message for the WCF service I'm trying to communicate with. The core xml data is the same (within the <Location/> node) but that needs to be wrapped in the Action for the in order for the WCF proxy to understand the call -- unless I'm understanding SOAP incorrectly.

Comment: In the insequence, you have to define your mediation logic..There are number of samples, in ESB docuemnation,which is helpful to you..

Comment: Yes, I was able to determine that. I'm mostly complete with the mediation logic.